"Essentially injective" functors and equivalence of categories
A functor $F: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is said to be essentially surjective if for all $D \in \mathcal D$, there exists a $C \in \mathcal C$ such that $FC \cong D$. Is there a corresponding notion of essentially injective functors? A potential definition could be: for all $C, C' \in \mathcal C$, if $FC = FC'$, then $C \cong C'$ (the preimages of any object in the range are isomorphic).
A well-known result is that $F$ is (part of) an equivalence if and only if $F$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective. What if we assume that $F$ is fully faithful and essentially injective? It is certainly not an equivalence in this case, but can we say anything about how the categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ (or even $FC$) are related?

You might have noticed that your first question can be answered by googling the term you asked for. I suggest to consider doing this next time.

Yes: a functor $F$ is essentially injective if the existence of an isomorphism $FC \cong FC'$ implies $C \cong C'$. Note that every fully faithful functor is essentially injective.

I agree with this answer except for the first  word, "Yes." The question had $FC=FC'$ whereas the answer has (correctly in my opinion) $FC\cong FC'$.

Indeed (but this is only a problem if you consider non-univalent, non-skeletal categories).

Your condition involving $FC=FC'$ does contradict the principle of equivalence. This is why one replaces it with $FC \cong FC'$.
A functor which is essentially injective and essentially surjective is just a functor that is bijective on isomorphism classes. This does tell us that the categories have the same classifications of its objects, but surely the categories don't have to be equivalent. As an extreme example, take the category of sets with bijective maps and the category of sets with injective maps (or even all maps). The isomorphism classes are the same.

Similarly, any morphism of monoids induces a functor between the corresponding one-object categories.  That's obviously always essentially injective and essentially surjective; but it's an equivalence if and only if the original morphism of monoids is an isomorphism.
